# API for login in a html template

Tags: django, rest

I want to have a API for login in a html template django.
**URLS.PY**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from Average import views
from Average.apis import *

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^add/fav/(?P<roll>[0-9]+)',add_fav),
    url(r'^favs/',get_favs),
    url(r'^auth/',authenticate)
]
```

**apis.py**

```
@api_view(['POST','GET'])
def authenticate(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        k = User.objects.all().filter(id=1)
        serialized = UserSerializer(k,many=True)
        return Response(serialized.data)
        #I just returned the superuser id. To check if it is working. Forget                                   
        #it
```

and finally my html template : 
**Template**

```
<form method="post" class="right" action="/api/auth/">
                <input style="width:200px" type="text" class="form-control line">
                <input style="width:200px" type="password" class="form-control line">
                <button class="btn btn-primary line">Login</button></form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding name for input tags in template. Thanks

```
        <form method="post" class="right" action="/api/auth/">
        <input style="width:200px" name="user" type="text" class="form-control line">
        <input style="width:200px" name="pwd" type="password" class="form-control line">
        <button class="btn btn-primary line">Login</button></form>
```